# Scraping window.location.href links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I print out links that contain `ftype2`?

I'm fairly new to bs4,from what I've been reading, the findAll or find_all method is only used for tags. It can't be used for windows.location.href kind of tags.

It might seem that regex is the last option, but I'm not sure how that will work since I can't figure out how to select those particular links because the select tag in bs4 doesn't work with
`Window.location.href`

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
import re
import urllib.parse

# specify the url 
r=requests.get("http://fztvseries.mobi/search.php?search=Why+women+kill&beginsearch=Search&vsearch=&by=series") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") 
mydivs = soup.find("div", {"class": "mainbox"})

w=mydivs.a["href"]

g=urllib.parse.unquote(w)
print(g)

seasons="https://fztvseries.mobi/"+g 
r=requests.get(seasons) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

episodes = [] 
for mydiv in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mainbox3"}):
    elink=mydiv.find('a')['href']
    #Episodes
    episodes.append("https://fztvseries.mobi/"+elink)

# Outside for loop

s1=requests.get(episodes[0])
soup=BeautifulSoup(s1.content, "html.parser") 
print(soup.findAll('a'))
```

This is the output, I need links with ftype=2

```
[<a href="//fztvseries.mobi/index.php"><img src="//fztvseries.mobi/logo/fztvseries1.png" width="350px"/></a>, <a href="//fztvseries.mobi/index.php" style="padding:5px;"><img height="15" src="//fztvseries.mobi/logo/justlogo.png" width="15"/></a>, <a href="https://fzstudios.app/"><img alt="Download App" src="https://fzstudios.app/img/promotion/promotion%20small%203.png" style="max-width: 100%; object-fit: contain"/></a>, <a href="https://t.me/fztvseries"><b><i><u>Join @fztvseries</u></i></b></a>, <a href="http://www.mobiletvshows.net/videos/Done/index.php?fformat=avi">In AVI</a>, <a href="http://www.mobiletvshows.net/videos/Done/index.php?fformat=mp4">In High MP4</a>, <a href="https://www.fzmovies.host">Visit FzMovies for HD Quality Mobile Movies in 3gp and Mp4 Format</a>, <a href="subfolder-Why Women Kill.htm">Why Women Kill</a>, <a href="tv.php">TV</a>, <a href="files-Why Women Kill--9338.htm" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Season 1</span></a>, <a href="files-Why Women Kill--9339.htm" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Season 2</span></a>, <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('missingepform').style.display='block';return false;">Report Missing Episode</a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=79204" id="dafgcebh" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=79204";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E01 - Murder Means Never Having to Say You" re="" sorry'="" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img ;'="" alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E01 - Murder Means Never Having to Say You' re="" sorry").innerhtml="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;" src="imdb_epimages/7222591.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=79204&amp;ftype=2" id="xtsvrqwu" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=79204&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=79204&amp;ftype=3" id="43y6125z" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=79204&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=80854" id="hegbadcf" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=80854";
                                          return false;'><div but="" d="" hair'="" i="" id="Why Women Kill - S01E02 - I" just="" kill="" like="" my="" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);" to="" washed="" ya,=""><img ;'="" alt="Why Women Kill" but="" d="" hair").innerhtml="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;" height="100px" i="" id="epimg" just="" kill="" like="" my="" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E02 - I' src="imdb_epimages/7298941.jpg" to="" washed="" width="100px" ya,=""/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=80854&amp;ftype=2" id="wrtuqvxs" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=80854&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=80854&amp;ftype=3" id="4zy35621" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=80854&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81212" id="adegbcfh" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81212";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E03 - I Killed Everyone He Did, But Backwards and in High Heels" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E03 - I Killed Everyone He Did, But Backwards and in High Heels").innerHTML="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;";' src="imdb_epimages/7298942.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81212&amp;ftype=2" id="twsxvrqu" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81212&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81212&amp;ftype=3" id="5y21z436" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81212&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81544" id="cedabhfg" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81544";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E04 - You Had Me at Homicide" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E04 - You Had Me at Homicide").innerHTML="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;";' src="imdb_epimages/7298943.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81544&amp;ftype=2" id="vwusxtrq" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81544&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81544&amp;ftype=3" id="5123y46z" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81544&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81855" id="dbefcgah" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81855";
                                          return false;'><div crying="" id="Why Women Kill - S01E05 - There" in="" murder'="" no="" s="" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img ;'="" alt="Why Women Kill" crying="" height="100px" id="epimg" in="" murder").innerhtml="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;" no="" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E05 - There' s="" src="imdb_epimages/7298944.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81855&amp;ftype=2" id="tusxrqwv" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81855&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81855&amp;ftype=3" id="35246zy1" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81855&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81990" id="ebacfhdg" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81990";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E06 - Practically Lethal in Every Way" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E06 - Practically Lethal in Every Way").innerHTML="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;";' src="imdb_epimages/_1_6_Practically.Lethal.in.Every.Way.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81990&amp;ftype=2" id="qtvuswrx" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81990&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=81990&amp;ftype=3" id="z124y653" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=81990&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=82237" id="hgefbcda" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=82237";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E07 - I Found Out What the Secret to Murder Is: Friends. Best Friends. " style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E07 - I Found Out What the Secret to Murder Is: Friends. Best Friends. ").innerHTML="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;";' src="imdb_epimages/7298946.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=82237&amp;ftype=2" id="twrqxusv" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=82237&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=82237&amp;ftype=3" id="z15y4263" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=82237&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=83158" id="fbdchega" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=83158";
                                          return false;'><div --="" a="" account="" break="" else="" id="Why Women Kill - S01E08 - Marriages Don" is="" it's="" just="" murder="" of="" on="" something="" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);" symptom="" t="" that="" up="" wrong'=""><img --="" ;'="" a="" account="" alt="Why Women Kill" break="" else="" height="100px" id="epimg" is="" it's="" just="" murder="" of="" on="" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E08 - Marriages Don' something="" src="imdb_epimages/7352469.jpg" symptom="" t="" that="" up="" width="100px" wrong").innerhtml="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=83158&amp;ftype=2" id="qrwtvxsu" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=83158&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=83158&amp;ftype=3" id="y346512z" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=83158&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=84139" id="fedbchga" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=84139";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E09 - I Was Just Wondering What Makes Dames Like You So Deadly" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E09 - I Was Just Wondering What Makes Dames Like You So Deadly").innerHTML="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;";' src="imdb_epimages/7352471.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=84139&amp;ftype=2" id="qwxturvs" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=84139&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=84139&amp;ftype=3" id="y1352z46" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=84139&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=85099" id="gbdchfea" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=85099";
                                          return false;'><div id="Why Women Kill - S01E10 - Kill Me as If It Were the Last Time" style="display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom;border:1px solid gray;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#ffeedd, purple);"><img alt="Why Women Kill" height="100px" id="epimg" onerror='document.getElementById("Why Women Kill - S01E10 - Kill Me as If It Were the Last Time").innerHTML="&lt;b&gt;&lt;small&gt;Why Women Kill&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/b&gt;";' src="imdb_epimages/7406286.jpg" width="100px"/></div></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=85099&amp;ftype=2" id="rsqvutwx" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=85099&amp;ftype=2";
                                          return false;'><small>(High MP4)</small></a>, <a href="episode.php?fileid=85099&amp;ftype=3" id="3124yz65" onclick='window.open("https://stawhoph.com/4/4115624");
                                          window.location.href="episode.php?fileid=85099&amp;ftype=3";
                                          return false;'><small>(WEBM)</small></a>, <a href="faq.php">FAQs</a>]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the correct formatting (such as line breaks) and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've modified it.

Comment: I've added a comment. @Muhteva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you are looking for `a` elements whose `href` contains the text **ftype=2**. Below is the code you can use to do so:

```py
links = [el['href'] for el in soup.select("a[href*='ftype=2']")]
print(links)
```

`*=` css selector looks for the partial texts in the given attribute. In other words, `href*='ftype=2'` looks for the `href` attributes that contain the text ftype=2.

Output:

```py
['episode.php?fileid=79204&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=80854&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=81212&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=81544&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=81855&ftype=2',
'episode.php?fileid=81990&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=82237&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=83158&ftype=2', 
'episode.php?fileid=84139&ftype=2',
'episode.php?fileid=85099&ftype=2']
```

Comment: Its only the window.location.href links i want.

Comment: I only want links like this "episode.php?fileid=81855&ftype=2" ,I don't want any other thing in the output. I don't want window.open  or return false I just want one set of  ftype=2 links since there are two sets showing now.

Comment: It worked, done.